# Django styling included templates

Tags: django

I have three files. 
My base.html:

```
{% load static %}

<head>
    <link href="{% static 'base/css/normalize.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="{% static 'base/css/base.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    {% block styling %}
    {% endblock %}
</head>
<body>
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
</body>
```

Project.html:

```
{% extends "base/base.html" %}
{% load sass_tags %}
{% load static %}

{% block styling %}
<title>Project</title>
<link href="{% sass_src 'dashboard/scss/project.scss' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="project-container">
        {% include "dashboard/tree.html" %}...
```

and tree.html:

```
{% load sass_tags %}

<link href="{% sass_src 'dashboard/scss/tree.scss' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<section class="tree">
    <ul class="tree__root">...
```

To summarize above code; project.html extends from base.html, and project.html is also including tree.html. This works as intended and the styling is applied correctly as well. But I'm unhappy about the place of the styling. When I include the styling of tree.html it is put in the body of the DOM. I want it to be in the head.

I have tried extending base.html in tree.html and using `{% block styling %}`, didn't work. Also I tried defining a head in tree.html which didn't work either (no surprise there).

So as far as I can see I am left with two choices.

- Include the styling in the styling block of project.html (which doesn't seem to make sense to me, why include the styling for a template in another template?)
- Include the styling in tree.html, but have the link outside of the head (which seems bad practice to me)

What is the best practice for such a thing?